# How to change CSS pseudo-class element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change this image using javascript:

```
 dance:active { background-image: url("myImage.png") }
```

You can use

```
document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundImage = url(image);
```

to change

```
#element {background-image: url(image)}
```

I would like to change the image of when the element is active using javascript. Thanks!

Comment: please post jsfiddle link for it...is the css not working?

Comment: Right, please share some markup. From your description I do not fully understand what you try to archive.

Comment: Ok. I can change my background image in html with document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundImage = url(image). This is like using #element {background-image: url(image)} in css. I would like to change the image in #element:active {background-image: url(image)} in javascript. How could I do that?

Comment: You should put more information into your question, its quite hard to understand why you really want to achive.

Comment: What are the potential reasons for the active-state image needing to change? Do you need to be able to change the image to any arbitrary URL, or just switch between a fixed number of different images?

Comment: You may comsider change your question into "How to change CSS pseudo-class element using JavaScript".

Comment: Thanks! I just learned about the pseudo classes. I am creating a button that makes a person dance, and I would like to be able to change the dance styles. I have 2 images for every dance, one for the idle pose (when button is not clicked) , and another for the active pose(when button is clicked). I know how to change the idle pose, but how do I edit the active pose using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

You can have multiple classes in your CSS :

```
element.dance1 { stuff }
element.dance1:active { active stuff }
element.dance2 { stuff 2 }
element.dance2:active { active stuff 2 }
```

and then change the class of the element in javascript:

```
document.getElementById(element).className = dance1/dance2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery to achive what you want. `dance: active` is CSS Pseudo-classes. Learn more about [Pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

The demo change the div color when mouse down and switch the color back when mouse up. Leave comments if this is not what you want.

```
$("#dance").on("mousedown", function () {
    $("#dance").css("background", "blue");
}).on("mouseup", function(){
    $("#dance").css("background", "black");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x_li/5nkvms8q/

and jQuery can also do the following

```
$('#damce:checked').val();
```

Comment: That JSFiddle link gave me a 404 error. Could you see what happened there? Thanks!